# Can I include (similar styled) art/characters from other apps in my free trading card game app?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, trademark

Say I wanted to make a free (+no ads etc.) app which is essentially a trading card game but the cards consist of characters designed to be similar to ones from other apps. For example, one card would be a different coloured 'Angry Bird' styled bird.

Is creating this art in my free trading card app considered trademark/IP infringement?

I.e. creating new concept art (similar styled) but not using actual characters by Angry Birds, like this:

[image: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/a7/9c/89/a79c89758cbf6f6e7258d4a81979ea98.jpg]

If so, would I need to get license/permission from each app I wanted to include?

Comment: And a suppose a follow up question would be, if I labelled/associated the card as an 'Angry Bird' in some way, that would make it more likely to infringe or?

Comment: Is that artwork completely yours? Does that character exist in the game?

Comment: It was just used for reference, if i used that pink (angry bird-styled) art as a single card in my game (when pink doesnt exist in angry birds) would it be fine? If it was just styled like an angry bird and was one of many cards (rest not angry birds but similar idea; each card (similar) to one character from every popular app)